# React - Google Maps component not rendering after componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps, google-maps-react

I'm just having trouble with my Google Maps rendering when a search (with a postcode) happens. It seems like the map is rendering the null map centre, and then not re-rendering after setState in componentDidMount(), as the map is rendered blank/grey but with a hard refresh the map will load with the postcode. I've tried using componentWillMount() without any luck, anyone have any suggestions?

This is the code for my search page:

```
class SearchContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      map_centre: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    axios
      .get("api/v1/search?postcode=" + values.postcode)
      .then(response => {
        var mapCentre = response.data.map_centre;
        this.setState({
          map_centre: mapCentre
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="map" className="padding-left">
        <GoogleMapComponent
          townCenters={this.state.townCenters}
          schools={this.state.schools}
          supermarkets={this.state.supermarkets}
          hotels={this.state.hotels}
          airports={this.state.airports}
          trainStations={this.state.trainStations}
          map_centre={this.state.map_centre}
          onMapMounted={this.handleMapMounted}
          onDragEnd={this.handleMapChange}
          onZoomChanged={this.handleMapChange}
          onMarkerClick={this.handleAdspaceShow}
          googleMapURL={url}
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100vh`, width: `100%` }} />}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100vh`, width: `100%` }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100vh`, width: `100%` }} />}
        />
        <img
          src={mapSearch}
          id="map-search-button"
          onClick={this.toggleSearchInput}
        />
        <input
          id="map-search-input"
          className="form-control d-none"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Enter new location"
          aria-label="Search"
          onChange={this.handlePostcodeChange}
          onKeyPress={this.handleNewSearch}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code for my Google Maps component:

```
const GoogleMapComponent = withScriptjs(
  withGoogleMap(props => (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={13}
      defaultCenter={props.map_centre}
      onDragEnd={props.onDragEnd}
      onZoomChanged={props.onZoomChanged}
      ref={props.onMapMounted}
    />
  ))
);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the prop `center` instead of `map_centre` on the `GoogleMapComponent` component?

Comment: @Tholle can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: I have not used this library myself, but [looking at the documentation](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#googlemap) the `GoogleMap` component doesn't seem to have a `map_centre` prop, but a `center` prop.

Comment: I think it's slightly different, as I'm not hardcoding a defaultCenter. I am getting a defaultCenter in my componentDidMount function

Comment: Yes, but you are passing the value you get from the axios reqeust as `map_centre` to the map. The map doesn't know what to do with `map_centre`, only `center`.

Comment: But map_centre is just a state name, and you can see that it's getting tracked back down to the actual GoogleMap Component on defaultCenter which is the thing that the map actually does something with?

Comment: Yes, you're right, but `defaultCenter` is only the initial center. It will not be used by the map again after the initial rendering. If you use `center` on the `GoogleMap` instead it will most likely update as expected.

Comment: Ah I understand, thought it would be after each rendering. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! You're welcome.

Comment: Consider [accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if you feel it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultCenter` will only be used by the map for the initial render, so it will not have any effect if you change this value later.

If you use the `center` prop instead it will work as expected.

```
const GoogleMapComponent = withScriptjs(
  withGoogleMap(props => (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={13}
      center={props.map_centre}
      onDragEnd={props.onDragEnd}
      onZoomChanged={props.onZoomChanged}
      ref={props.onMapMounted}
    />
  ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific with the library you are using...you have added the tags "google-maps-react" and "react-google-map" and both are different libraries...

google-maps-react = https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react

react-google-map = https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/

Anyway, I can see 2 options:

solution 1:

Add a conditional that renders  GoogleMapComponent only if map_centre is not null.

```
  render() {
    if(this.state.map_centre){
      return (
        <div id="map" className="padding-left">
          <GoogleMapComponent
            townCenters={this.state.townCenters}
            schools={this.state.schools}
            supermarkets={this.state.supermarkets}
            hotels={this.state.hotels}
            airports={this.state.airports}
            trainStations={this.state.trainStations}
            map_centre={this.state.map_centre}
            onMapMounted={this.handleMapMounted}
            onDragEnd={this.handleMapChange}
            onZoomChanged={this.handleMapChange}
            onMarkerClick={this.handleAdspaceShow}
            googleMapURL={url}
            loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100vh`, width: `100%` }} />}
            containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100vh`, width: `100%` }} />}
            mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100vh`, width: `100%` }} />}
           />
          <img
          src={mapSearch}
          id="map-search-button"
          onClick={this.toggleSearchInput}
          />
          <input
          id="map-search-input"
          className="form-control d-none"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Enter new location"
          aria-label="Search"
          onChange={this.handlePostcodeChange}
          onKeyPress={this.handleNewSearch}
          />
      </div>);
     }
     return <div> Loading.. </div>;
  }
```

solution 2:

Set a default lat/lng (not null) before you get the response.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      map_centre: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }
    };
  }
```